# Tensorflow serving - How to use large word embeddings?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, assets, tensorflow-serving, word-embedding

I am kind of new to Tensorflow. I have the simple LSTM task to classify text. Im converting words to vectors with word2vec with 300 dims with `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`
my word embeddings are in `np.array` and I am loading it with `np.load()`.

When I save the model either with `tf.train.Saver() or builder.save()` my exported model is ~1.5 GB big. I am unable to load this model to Tensorflow serving due to size restrictions.

I have read something about assets and storing external files to asset directory. Does it apply also to wordvectors? How to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: My np.array with wordvectors is actually 1,5 GB big. What is the proper way to serve a model in tensorflow serving with such big "embedding layer"?

Comment: I have found that when I reduce model size under 1 GB then it started to work. Does anyone know how to increase the limit ? I didn't found answer on the internet yet.